Automate deployment of Lightning Email Template Letterhead assignment
Recently an ability to deploy Lightning Email Templates has been added.
However, Lightning Email Template metadata doesn't contain any information about the letterhead being used, which means this has to be done manually.
Is there any way to automate deployment of Lightning Email Template Letterhead assignment?

Indeed Lightning Email Template metadata doesn't contain any information about the letterhead being used.
However, the records do.
This means we can use a simple data update script to migrate Letterhead assignment from one org to another like following.
First, run the following script on the source org where you have letterhead assigned.
sf data query -q "SELECT Name, DeveloperName, EnhancedLetterhead.Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName LIKE 'DesiredDeveloperNameStart%'" -r csv -o source_org> emailTemplate.csv

Next, execute the following script for the target org
sf data upsert bulk --sobject EmailTemplate --file  emailTemplate.csv --external-id Name --wait 5 -o target_org

It is possible to store the extracted email templates to letterhead assignments in csv file in repository and use it for automated CI/CD process.
Above assumes that letterheads are already migrated. If this isn't the case, they can be also migrated using data update scripts for the source org
sf data query -q "SELECT Description, LetterheadFooter, LetterheadHeader, Name FROM EnhancedLetterHead" -r csv -o source_org> enhancedletterhead.csv

and the destination org
sf data upsert bulk --sobject EnhancedLetterHead --file enhancedletterhead.csv --external-id Name --wait 5 -o target_org

